# Custom button on jqgrid keeps re-adding on every call - asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I added a custom button to the tool bar in jqgrid in my asp mvc model, but everytime a call to get data is made from the view to the controller(OnDataRequested), the button is re added again. Which means if five calls to get data, results in five separate buttons on the jqgrid. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code. Thanks.

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            var gridModel = new LibraryGridModel();
             SetupGrid(gridModel.LibraryGrid);
             return View(gridModel);
        }

         public virtual JsonResult OnDataRequested()
        {
             var gridModel = new LibraryGridModel();
              return gridModel.LibraryGrid.DataBind(GetFullLibrary().AsQueryable());
        }

     public void SetupGrid(JQGrid grid)
        {
            grid.DataUrl = Url.Action("OnDataRequested","Library");
            grid.MultiSelect = true;
            grid.MultiSelectMode = MultiSelectMode.SelectOnCheckBoxClickOnly;
        }
```

Grid grid = new{  ToolBarSettings = { ShowRefreshButton = true, ShowSearchButton = true, ShowSearchToolBar = true, 
                                                              ToolBarAlign = ToolBarAlign.Left, CustomButtons = new List
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        new JQGridToolBarButton
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                        Text = "Add to Library",
                                                                                                        ToolTip = "Add the selected session to mine",
                                                                                                        ButtonIcon = "ui-icon-plusthick",
                                                                                                        Position = ToolBarButtonPosition.Last,
                                                                                                        OnClick = "AddMultipleSessionsToLibrary",
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }},

I'm adding the custom button in my LibraryGrid class. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the custom button from your GridModel. Then, add it in the index action call only.
Model:

```
Grid grid = new{ ToolBarSettings = { ShowRefreshButton = true, ShowSearchButton = true, ShowSearchToolBar = true, ToolBarAlign = ToolBarAlign.Left }},
```

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
            {
                var gridModel = new LibraryGridModel();
                gridModel.ToolBarSettings.CustomButtons.Add(
                     new JQGridToolBarButton
                     {
                         Text = "Add to Library",
                         ToolTip = "Add the selected session to mine",
                         ButtonIcon = "ui-icon-plusthick",
                         Position = ToolBarButtonPosition.Last,
                         OnClick = "AddMultipleSessionsToLibrary"
                     }
                 );
                 SetupGrid(gridModel.LibraryGrid);
                 return View(gridModel);
            }
         public virtual JsonResult OnDataRequested()
        {
             var gridModel = new LibraryGridModel();
              return gridModel.LibraryGrid.DataBind(GetFullLibrary().AsQueryable());
        }

 public void SetupGrid(JQGrid grid)
    {
        grid.DataUrl = Url.Action("OnDataRequested","Library");
        grid.MultiSelect = true;
        grid.MultiSelectMode = MultiSelectMode.SelectOnCheckBoxClickOnly;
    }
```

Comment: The onDataRequested is used by the grid to request for additional data, such as when the user goes to a new page on the grid, so that call has to be there. How do I pass a reference of the model to the OnDataRequested, as I said earlier, it is call by jqgrid directly. Please explain some more If I'm missing the point. Thanks.

Comment: can you please post the LibraryGridModel?

Comment: The model is posted. I tried passing in the model to OnDataRequested as suggested, but that didn't work. Thx

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer.  You need to remove the button add from the Viewmodel.  Then add it in the Index Action Method.

Comment: Same problem is still occurring...any ideas?

Comment: you removed the custom button from the Model right?  Now you only add it in the controller?

Comment: Yes, I only add it in the Index() of the controller. It seems so weird.

Comment: i think i would take the code from their example above and get it working in my project.  Then slowly modify it and test it to accommodate what you are trying to do.  I am out of ideas.  good luck!

Comment: I figured out the problem. In my ajax call on my view, I'm calling th append() method, which i guess adds another button each time, changing it to clearing the html and adding each time fixed the problem.